# Get corners in a grid?

Tags: python, tile

I have a grid with a functioned defined as:

```
def getCorners(width, height, tile1)
```

Say the grid looks something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8
```

I need to find the 1, 4, 5, and 8 in this case. I established the variables and I feel confident that they will work.

```
firsttile = 1  # This is the first tile of the grid
TR_tile = width  # Top right tile
max = width * height
BL_tile = max - width + 1  # Bottom left tile
lasttile = max  # This is the last tile of the grid
```

I want to try and write conditional statements that will be true for every grid regardless of the size.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you mean for your grid to have unequal rows?  I'd have to say that it doesn't have a lower-right corner, you'd need to add a 15 to it.

Comment: please edit your answer to demonstrate what your grid looks like, are you wanting all possible grids for given array?

Comment: The rows in your `grid` don't all have the same length. This make assumption about how how it;s laid out tricky. Is that way you intend. Please [edit] your question and fix the sample grid.

Comment: I don't understand what you're actually asking for here. What kind of conditional statement do you want? A check if a given tile is one of the corner tiles? Why not just an `in` check with a set containing the four values you calculated?

Comment: Say for example width=5, height=5 and tile number is 17. I want to check if 17 is in any of the four corners of the grid using the variables that I created.

Comment: @Blckknght I corrected it, could you elaborate on what you were trying to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to test if a given number is on the corner of a grid defined by a width and height. You currently have code to calculate the numbers of the corner tiles, but you don't know where to go from there.

One way to solve the problem is to use the calculations you're currently doing, and compare their results with the given number. You could use a bunch of `==` comparisons, or you could put the computed corner values into a container of some kind and use `in` to do all the comparisons at once:

```
# do your code first, then...
if tile1 == firsttile or tile1 == TR_tile or tile1 == BL_tile or tile1 == lasttile:
```

Or:

```
if tile1 in (firsttile, TR_tile, BL_tile, lasttile):
```

That approach will work, but it's not the most efficient. A better approach would divide the tile number by the width and use the result and the remainder to tell which column and row the tile is on. The corner tiles are on the first and last row and column (in any combination). Note that the computations are cleaner for zero-indexed tiles. If you need to stick with tile numbers that start at 1, you need to subtract one first:

```
# no setup computation needed
row, column = divmod(tile1-1, width)
if (row == 0 or row == height-1) and (column == 0 or column == width-1):
```